# Plotting classification boundary?

Tags: matlab, classification

I would like to plot the classification boundary for the model obtained using Logistic Regression in Matlab. Solutions other than in Matlab are welcome but I will need access to Logistic Regression code for modification.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation to [multinomial logistic regression](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/mnrfit.html) in Matlab shows two examples of how to draw classification boundaries.

If that's not what you need, you need to clarify your question, specifying how your case is different.

Comment: Thanks for the link to tutorial, but it shows how it fits the existing data. When I say classification boundary, it means a line which divides dataset into two classes. So, a future point is classified lying in class A if it lies on that side on line  where class A is predicted by the model.